# pthread-win32 extension sem_post_multiple

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, posix, pthreads-win32

I am currently building a thin C++ wrapper around pthreads for in-house use. Windows as well as QNX are targeted and fortunately the pthreads-win32 ports seems to work very well, while QNX is conformant to POSIX for our practical purposes.

Now, while implementing semaphores, I hit the function

```
sem_post_multiple(sem_t*, int)
```

which is apparently only available on pthreads-win32 but is missing from QNX. As the name suggests the function is supposed to increment the semaphore by the count given as second argument. As far as I can tell the function is not part of neither POSIX 1b nor POSIX 1c.

Although there is currently no requirement for said function I am still wondering why pthreads-win32 provides the function and whether it might be of use. I could try to mimic it for QNX using similar to the following:

```
sem_post_multiple_qnx(sem_t* sem, int count)
{
   for(;count > 0; --count)
   {
       sem_post(sem);
   }
}
```

What I am asking for are suggestion/advice on how to proceed. If consensus suggests to do implement the function for QNX I would also appreciate comments on whether the suggested code snipped is a viable solution.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I deliberately left out my fancy C++ class for clarity. For all folks suggesting boost to the rescue: it is not an option in my current project due to management reasons.

Comment: this is what happens when "management" get involved in technical decision making... :) If you don't need it why are you wasting your time wrapping it? To me the decision is clear, skip it...

Comment: Indeed, I would skip wrapping POSIX semaphores entirely unless you're sure you need them. Semaphores are a 1990s (or even earlier?) idiom for synchronization. POSIX mutexes, condition variables, rwlocks, and spinlocks are much more useful in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case semaphores are an optional extension in POSIX. E.g OS X doesn't seem to implement them fully. So if you are concerned with portability, you'd have to provide wrappers of the functionalities you need, anyhow.

Your approach to emulate an atomic    increment by iterated `sem_post` has    certainly downsides.

- It might be    performing badly,
  where usually    `sem_t` are used in
  performance    critical contexts.
- This operation would not be
  atomic. So confusing things might
  happen before you finish the loop.

I would stick to the just necessary, strictly POSIX conforming. Beware that `sem_timedwait` is yet another optional part of the semaphore option.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `sem_timedwait()` I missed than one being an extension, too because it is provided in QNX

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed implementation of `sem_post_multiple` doesn't play nicely with `sem_getvalue`, since `sem_post_multiple` is an atomic increase and therefore it's not possible for a "simultaneous" call to `sem_getvalue` to return any of the intermediate values.

Personally I'd want to leave them both out: trying to add fundamental synchronization operations to a system which lacks them is a mug's game, and your wrapper might soon cease to be "thin". So don't get into it unless you have code that uses `sem_post_multiple`, that you absolutely have to port.

Answer (score 0):

sem_post_multiple() is a non-standard helper function introduced by the win32-pthreads maintainers. Your implementation isn't the same as theirs because the multiple decrements aren't atomic.  Whether or not this is a problem depends on the intended use. (Personally, I wouldn't try to implement this function unless/until the need arises.)

Comment: I had a glimse at their implementation in the meantime and indeed their code is quite different from a naive loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question.  +1.

I agree with the current prevailing consensus here that it is probably not a good idea to implement that function. While your proposed implementation would probably be work just fine in most situations, there are definitely conditions in which the results could be dramatically different due to the non-atomicity.  The following is one (extremely) contrived situation:

- Start thread A which calls sem_post_multiple( s, 10 )
- Thread B waiting on s is released.  Thread B kills thread A.

In the above unfriendly scenario, the atomic version would have incremented the semaphore by 10.  With non-atomic version, it may only be incremented once.  This example is certainly not likely in the real world. For example, the killing of a thread is almost always a bad idea not to mention the fact that it could leave the semaphore object in an invalid state.  The Win32 implementation could leave a mutex lock on the semaphore - [see this for why](http://sources-redhat.mirrors.airband.net/pthreads-win32/sources/pthreads-w32-2-8-0-release/sem_post_multiple.c).

Comment: There is absolutely no way to kill a thread that doesn't want to be killed. `sem_post` is not a cancellation point, so `sem_post_multiple` would not have any cancellation points in it unless you do something silly implementing it. And of course you can always disable cancellation for the duration of an operation.

Comment: By absolutely, of course I mean without invoking undefined behavior. Surely there are UB ways involving poking at random memory addresses... :-)

Comment: @R - I agree.  That's also why I used the words "extremely" and "contrived".